# How to pass the i index value to a command in R?

Tags: r

Fairly new to using R; would appreciate any help. I want to pass the i value from a for loop to an R command. This is what I am stuck with.

```
for i in colnames(df) table(df$i)
```

The i value is not being used the way I hoped.

If I did table(df$col1) where col1 is the name of column in df I get a result. i holds "col1".

Why doesn't it work and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

We need to use `[[` instead of `$`.  In addition, add the brackets as well.  In a `for` loop if we don't `print`, it won't show up in the console.

```
for(i in colnames(df)) print(table(df[[i]]))
```

---

Or if we want to store the output, initialize a `list` and assign the output into the `list`

```
lst1 <- vector('list', ncol(df))
names(lst1) <- colnames(df)
for(i in colnames(df)) lst1[[i]] <- table(df[[i]])
```

---

The `R` way would be using `*apply` functions

```
lapply(df, table)
```